# CardFragment not showing in FragmentGridPagerAdapter - Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to make a simple GridPager with Android Wear. The problem is that I can swipe through different rows and columns but the card is not visible..
Besides I get this warning in the log:

```
06-16 07:49:55.883    1739-1739/ W/GridViewPager﹕ Unknown child view, not claimed by adapter: android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView{2231190b V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
```

Code activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                final GridViewPager mGridPager = (GridViewPager) stub.findViewById(R.id.pager);
                mGridPager.setAdapter(new SampleGridPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, getFragmentManager()));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Code adapter:

```
public class SampleGridPagerAdapter extends FragmentGridPagerAdapter {
    private final Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<SimpleRow> mPages;

    public SampleGridPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
        initPages();
    }

    private void initPages() {
        Log.i("adapter", "init pages");
        mPages = new ArrayList<>();

        SimpleRow row1 = new SimpleRow();
        row1.addPages(new SimplePage("Title1", "Text1", R.drawable.ic_full_cancel, R.drawable.ic_full_sad));
        row1.addPages(new SimplePage("Title2", "Text2", R.drawable.ic_full_cancel, R.drawable.ic_full_sad));

        SimpleRow row2 = new SimpleRow();
        row2.addPages(new SimplePage("Title3", "Text3", R.drawable.ic_full_cancel, R.drawable.ic_full_sad));

        SimpleRow row3 = new SimpleRow();
        row3.addPages(new SimplePage("Title4", "Text4", R.drawable.ic_full_cancel, R.drawable.ic_full_sad));

        SimpleRow row4 = new SimpleRow();
        row4.addPages(new SimplePage("Title5", "Text5", R.drawable.ic_full_cancel, R.drawable.ic_full_sad));
        row4.addPages(new SimplePage("Title6", "Text6", R.drawable.ic_full_cancel, R.drawable.ic_full_sad));

        mPages.add(row1);
        mPages.add(row2);
        mPages.add(row3);
        mPages.add(row4);
    }




    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return mPages.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Drawable getBackgroundForPage(int row, int column) {

        return mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_alarm_day);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentColumnForRow(int row, int currentColumn) {
        return currentColumn;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(int row) {
        return mPages.get(row).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getFragment(int row, int column) {
        SimplePage page = mPages.get(row).getPages(column);
        return CardFragment.create(page.getmTitle(), page.getmText());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view.equals(o);
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out here!

Comment: Hej, can you post your SimpleRow class? :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove :

```
 @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return view.equals(o);
    }
```

apparently this turns out to be false all the time on my side.